# On iOS UITextChecker’s execution is extremely slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

On iOS `UITextChecker’s` execution is extremely slow, I want to add and remove (`learnWord:/unlearnWord:`) near about 50,000 in my project. By this process it will took more than 5 to 6 hours. Is there is any way to optimize it? Or any easy alternative solution to this?

I tried following demo:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSString *word = @"test";

    CFTimeInterval startTime1 = CACurrentMediaTime();
    BOOL hasLearnWord = [UITextChecker hasLearnedWord:word];
    CFTimeInterval endTime1 = CACurrentMediaTime();
    NSLog(@"Execution Time 1: %f, hasLearnWord: %@", endTime1 - startTime1, hasLearnWord ? @"Yes" : @"No");

    CFTimeInterval startTime2 = CACurrentMediaTime();
    [UITextChecker unlearnWord:word];
    CFTimeInterval endTime2 = CACurrentMediaTime();
    NSLog(@"Execution Time 2: %f", endTime2 - startTime2);

    CFTimeInterval startTime3 = CACurrentMediaTime();
    [UITextChecker learnWord:word];
    CFTimeInterval endTime3 = CACurrentMediaTime();
    NSLog(@"Execution Time 3: %f", endTime3 - startTime3);

    return YES;
}
```

**Result:**

```
2014-03-05 05:48:20.064 demo[316:60b] Execution Time 1: 0.593178, hasLearnWord: Yes
2014-03-05 05:48:20.643 demo[316:60b] Execution Time 2: 0.576586
2014-03-05 05:48:21.219 demo[316:60b] Execution Time 3: 0.575505
```